# Segmentation fault when appending to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a linked list and so far I keep running into a segmentation fault.

Through some testing I have manged to find out where it happens, but I'm not sure why it happens.

It triggers on the line: `tempo->fileName = str;`
Is it due to me trying to make an assignment on a pointer or is it something else I'm not aware of?

```
typedef struct listnode{
  struct listnode* next;
  char* fileName;
} listnode;

struct listnode* head;

//This section of code will be dedicated to the creation and management
//of the listnode functions

listnode* createNode(char* str, listnode* next){
  listnode* tempo;
  tempo = (listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));

  if(tempo = NULL){
    printf("Error creating space for new node.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  tempo->fileName = str;
  tempo->next = next;

  return tempo;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Hint: What does `tempo = NULL` do?

Comment: This is why you should use `-Wall -Wextra` when you compile

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the conditional `if(tempo = NULL)`. Instead of comparing `tempo == NULL`, you're assigning `tempo = NULL`. Then you do `tempo->fileName = str`, which is actually accessing a `NULL` pointer. Just because you're writing a conditional it doesn't make the `=` operator an equality operator, it's still an assignment operator. The comparison operator is `==`.

Change the conditional to:

```
if(tempo == NULL)
```